# How to get the data for today's date from multiple cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to get the data  (profit) every day for the actual day displayed so I can paste it into a daily report. I figured I would create a cell with todays date (=TODAY) and then use some kind of IF function, but not sure how.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column `A` contains dates, formatted as "dd/mm", then to get the "Start" value you could use:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:N,2,FALSE)
```

Similarly, the "Finish" value would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:N,3,FALSE)
```

And "Profit" would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:N,4,FALSE)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A:N,14,FALSE)
```

(depending on whether you want the "Profit" from column D or column N)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks much cleaner than what I managed to come up with haha. Brute force but works :)

=IF(A36=C1,D35,IF(A35=C1,D34,IF(A34=C1,D33,IF(A33=C1,D32,IF(A32=C1,D31,IF(A31=C1,D30,IF(A30=C1,D29,IF(A29=C1,D28,IF(A28=C1,D27,IF(A27=C1,D26,IF(A26=C1,D25,IF(A25=C1,D24,IF(A24=C1,D23,IF(A23=C1,D22,IF(A22=C1,D21,IF(A21=C1,D20,IF(A20=C1,D19,IF(A19=C1,D18,IF(A18=C1,D17,IF(A17=C1,D16,IF(A16=C1,D15,IF(A15=C1,D14,IF(A14=C1,D13,IF(A13=C1,D12,IF(A12=C1,D11,IF(A11=C1,D10,IF(A10=C1,D9,IF(A9=C1,D8,IF(A8=C1,D7,IF(A7=C1,D6))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))